# Show that exponential funtion from $\mathbb{R}$ to unit circle is continuous.

Tags: general-topology

Show that $\exp :\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{S}^1$ defined by $f(t)=e^{2\pi i t}$ is continuous surjection. I know this is an easy problem but I can't do the continuity by open set definition. My attempt: Let $U$ be a open set in $\mathbb{S}^1$ defined by $U= \mathbb{S}^1-\{-1\}$  then it's inverse image is a disjoint union of open intervals $(n-1/2 , n+1/2).$ which is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$. Hence continuous is done. Is it correct?? Please, give your valuable response. But I can't find the surjectivity.

Comment: How exactly is this exponential map defined? I have my suspicions, but it's best if we don't have to guess.

Comment: To check  continuity it is not enough to pick a particular open set and then...

Comment: exponential function defined by $f(t)=e^{2\pi i t} $

Comment: Dear @Lost in Space, can you please help to prove it?

Comment: Can you think of a useful basis of open sets in $\mathbb{S}^1$?

Comment: @ Dan Rust, I don't know it. I am a beginner on algebraic topology. Can you please help me for continuity & surjectivity?

Comment: For $0 \leq s \leq 1$, $0 < \epsilon < \frac{1}{2}$ , Consider the open sets $U(s,\epsilon)$ given by $U(s,\epsilon) = \{e^{2\pi i (s+k)} \in \mathbb{S}^1 \mid |k| < \epsilon\}$. These form a basis for the topology on $\mathbb{S}^1$. What is the preimage in $\mathbb{R}$ of such a set under $f$?

Comment: For continuity, I wouldn't deal with bases of $\mathbb{S}^1$ but rather consider $\exp :\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not right. There are many discontinuous surjections $g:\Bbb R \to \Bbb S^1$ such that $g^{-1}(\Bbb S^1\setminus \{p\})$ is  open for each $p\in\Bbb S^1.$

A base (basis) $B$ for a topology is useful because we can often more easily prove something about the members of $B$ and then immediately obtain a result about all open sets. If $f^{-1}b$ is open for every $b\in B$ then $f^{-1}u$ is open for every open $u.$

A base for $\Bbb S^1$ is $B=\{\beta (a,b): a,b\in \Bbb R\}$ where $\beta (a,b)=\{\exp (2\pi it): a<t<b\}.$ What is $f^{-1}\beta (a,b)?$

Surjectivity: What exactly is $\Bbb S^1?$ And what is $\{f(t):t\in\Bbb R\}?$

Comment: @DanialWainfleet... Is $f^{-1}(\beta(a, b)) = \cup (a, b) $.??

Comment: $\mathbb{S}^1 =\{(x, y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2=1 \}.$

Comment: Is $\{ f(t) : t\in\mathbb{R} \} $, then what is $t$  ? Can anybody help me?

Comment: $f^{-1}\beta (a,b)=\cup_{n\in\Bbb Z}(a+2n\pi,b+2n\pi). $.... I don't understand what you mean by "what is $t$?" in your comment.

Comment: @ DanielWainfleet, thanks a lot. Sorry please leave the previous comment . Dear sir, can you please help me another prblm?? The problem is how to prove  this $exp: (-1/2 ,1/2)\to\mathbb{S}^1/\{-1\} $ 
           is  surjective .?? I can't understand how to do it? Plz tell something sir.

Comment: The correct definition of $\Bbb S^1$ in this problem is not $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:x^2+y^2=1\}.$ It is $\{x+yi\in\Bbb C:x,y\in\Bbb R\land x^2+y^2=1\}.$ For $t\in\Bbb R$ we have $\exp (2\pi it)=\cos 2\pi t+i\sin 2\pi t.$  If $-1\ne x+yi$ with $x,y\in\Bbb R$ and $x^2+y^2=1$ then there exists $t\in (-1/2,1/2)$ such that $\cos 2\pi t=x$ and $\sin 2\pi t=y.$ Consider the points $P=(x,y), O=(0,0), J=(1,0)$ in $\Bbb R^2 .$  Obtain $t$ by defining  the counter-clockwise angle $JOP$ as equal to $2\pi t$ radians.

Comment: again thanks sir. Here I got $t=\frac{1}{2\pi} .cos^{-1}(x) , ~\textrm{and } ~ t=\frac{1}{2\pi} sin^{-1}(x). $  Is it correct sir.??

Comment: Yes. Correct......................